# Array.copy two lambdas, difficult with using the second in linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, select, lambda

i have big problem with explanation code under, meanwhile i made two loops function which does the same thing. I send my code to friend to tell me if it is possible to make is simplier :) So i get something like that.

```
Array.Copy(
    myImageData
        .Select(
            (b, index) =>
                (
                    index > rooflimit && index < floorlimit && b == 252 &&
                    (myImageData[index + width] == 0 || (myImageData[index + width] > 168 && myImageData[index + width] < 173)) &&
                    myImageData[index - width] == 252 &&
                    myImageData[index - (2 * width)] == 159
                ) ? (byte)172 : b
        ).ToArray(),
    rooflimit + 1,
    myImageData,
    rooflimit + 1,
    floorlimit - rooflimit - 1
);
```

My loops was doing something like that (above do the same thing):

1. when you get all pixelse, copy them to array of bytes
2. find all pixels which have value 255, pixel under has 0 or it is from range 168-173
3. pixel above has value 255 and pixel 2 times above has value 159
4. if i found that pixel change that value to 172
5. *** pixel checking starts from the second row <strike>[0][1]</strike>[2], and finish before last row, to be able check pixels above and under of current pixel ***

I get almost about that code above, however i don't understand that part which starts with:

```
rooflimit + 1, 
myImageData, 
rooflimit + 1, 
floorlimit - rooflimit - 1);
```

So i ask you for a help, thanks!
PS. please change topic if it is not good specified.

Comment: Array.Copy function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx

Comment: I have reformatted heavily the code. Let's see if it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last four parameters are the last parameters to [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx). Your code would be clearer if you split it up:

```
byte[] tmp = myImageData.Select([... big lambda expression ...])
                        .ToArray();

Array.Copy(tmp, rooflimit + 1, 
           myImageData, rooflimit + 1,
           floorlimit - rooflimit - 1);
```

I would also be very tempted to use a separate method instead of a lambda expression here - it's too complicated to be readable, really.

Comment: would it be good to compare Array.Copy() to Marshall.Copy() ?

Comment: @Cooldown4seconds: No, I don't think so. You're not trying to marshal for interop purposes - you're just copying part of one array into another.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better see [MSDN Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) for this:

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified
>   source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the
>   specified destination index. The length and the indexes are specified
>   as 32-bit integers.